# @Html.ValidationMessageFor displays error message before user input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

In the model:

```
public class Student {

[Required(ErrorMessage = "name is a required field")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "school is a required field")]
public string School { get; set; }

}
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult StudentView()
{
return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentViewPost(Student model)
{
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
....
....
}
}
```

And in my view, i have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.School)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.School)
}
```

But when i go to the view page, the validation error messages are already displayed (on load), even before i get a chance to enter any input. Is there any reason why this could be happening? Could .NET be seeing this GET page as a POST page on load somehow and therefore display the error message? I'm not sure why this is happening and any thoughts/ideas would be great.

Comment: post you `[HttpGet]` action method also.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Something else must be triggering validation. Do you have any scripts on the page other than the `jquery-*.js`files?

Comment: All the javascript i have on the page is jquery.

Comment: How are you calling the page? Put a break point in each method and check which is being hit. You have a GET method named `StudentView` and a POST method named `StudentViewPost` so there is no relationship between these if you using `@using (Html.BeginForm()){`. You need to post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some issues in your Html.Beginform()

Normally you should write this begin blog as follow,
Example if your controller name is Student then,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("StudentViewPost", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.School)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.School)
}
```

Comment: This will produce the identical output in the form tag as OP usage. It has nothing to do with validation.

Answer (score -1):

You have not specifed the form method which will invoke the validations on Action 
use following syntax

`@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
}`

Comment: This will produce the identical output in the form tag as OP usage. It has nothing to do with validation.